# how to generate link from mysql query results in php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am just starting out with php/mysql.  I have list of results from a mysql query in php code which I would like to show as output with links - so that I can use "get" in 2nd page to process chosen link. My present code (based on other responses from this forum) is:

```
**while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=' .
      urlencode($row['Firm_Name']). '</a><br/>';
}**
```

I know that my mysql query is returning correct results, because if I echo them directly, I see results.  But with above code, I see nothing.  Source code with present code on output page looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=Goodman+Acker%2C+PC</a><br/><a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=Morganroth+%26+Morganroth%2C+PLLC</a><br/><a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=Dib%2C+Fagan+and+Brault%2C+PC</a><br/>
```

I know that I must be missing something simple with formatting - but I cannot figure out what.  I just want to show these firm names as links, with name ("lname") embedded in link title.

Thanks from a beginner for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not finishing your opening `a` tag and the tag has no content:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=' .
  urlencode($row['Firm_Name']). '</a><br/>';
```

Should be something like:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.org/?lname=' .
  urlencode($row['Firm_Name']). '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Firm_Name']) . '</a><br/>';
                                 ^^ closing quote and >
```